# How to prevent Suspicious Link message in GMail?

Tags: html, sharepoint, hyperlink, gmail

We are sending HTML emails from Microsoft365 to our clients and these emails contain a hyperlink to an item in a Sharepoint list in one of our Sharepoint sites.

I have only tested this in GMail, not sure whether the issue is only isolated here or on other email clients as well. When clicking the link in GMail, the below "Suspicious Link" popup message appears. Clicking 'Proceed' works, and brings the client to wherever he needs to be.

But we would like to avoid this popup message altogether.

The URL is in this format:

> https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/Lists/listname/EditForm.aspx?ID=123

I have tried 2 variants, and both are having the same issue:

```
<a href="{theURL}">{theURLagain}</a>
```

and

```
<a href="{theURL}" alt="Link to Our Sharepoint">Link to our Sharepoint</a>
```

Anyone has an idea how we need to write the HTML to prevent this? Or is it not related to how the HTML is written?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The following thread is discussing the same question, I hope this may help

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4242603?hl=en&msgid=8208054

Answer extracted from the thread:

*This solved the problem for me:
Go to postmaster.google.com.
On the bottom-right, click the + button.
In the box that pops up, enter your authentication domain.
Next, prove that you own the domain by adding a DNS TXT or a DNS CNAME record.
After I completed that, I stopped getting that 'untrusted' message within a few minutes.*

Comment: How do we add a DNS TXT or CNAME record for a Sharepoint site? We don't own the domain. It's xyz.sharepoint.com